# In PL/SQL you have created a new function with the following header and declaration section

Tags: oracle, plsql

FUNCTION EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE
(p_emp_id IN NUMBER)
RETURN DATE
IS
v_emp_join_date DATE;
BEGIN

Which of the following statement is not accepted by the compiler for this function?

1. RETURN SYSDATE;
2. RETURN ('no date found');
3. RETURN v_date;
4. None of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3rd one, because oracle checks undeclared variables at compile time. 2nd one will return cast error only at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be argued to be either 3 or 4:

## Option 1:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE (
  p_emp_id IN NUMBER
)
RETURN DATE
IS
  v_emp_join_date DATE;
BEGIN
  RETURN SYSDATE;
END;
/
```

Compiles without errors.

## Option 2:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE (
  p_emp_id IN NUMBER
)
RETURN DATE
IS
  v_emp_join_date DATE;
BEGIN
  RETURN ('no date found');
END;
/
```

Compiles without errors.

If you try to execute the procedure:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_date DATE;
BEGIN
  v_date := EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE( 1 );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR( v_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) );
END;
/
```

Then it will output an exception:

> ```
> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_BUISIFXHIMAYWYOGMYBY.EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE", line 8
> ORA-06512: at line 4
> ```

But, this is a run-time exception and not a compile-time error.

However, if you do something quite silly:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = '"no date found"';
```

Then the PL/SQL block and the function runs without error and outputs the 1st of the current month:

> ```
> 2020-09-01
> ```

## Option 3, version 1:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE (
  p_emp_id IN NUMBER
)
RETURN DATE
IS
  v_emp_join_date DATE;
BEGIN
  RETURN v_date;
END;
/
```

Gives the following compile-time error:

```sql
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

> ```
> NAME                  | TYPE     | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT                                            | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER
> :-------------------- | :------- | -------: | ---: | -------: | :---------------------------------------------- | :-------- | -------------:
> EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE | FUNCTION |        1 |    8 |       10 | PLS-00201: identifier 'V_DATE' must be declared | ERROR     |            201
> EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE | FUNCTION |        2 |    8 |        3 | PL/SQL: Statement ignored                       | ERROR     |              0
> ```

## Option 3, version 2:

However, if you form the procedure as:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMPLOYEE_JOINING_DATE (
  p_emp_id IN NUMBER
)
RETURN DATE
IS
  v_emp_join_date DATE;
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    v_date DATE := DATE '1970-01-01';
  BEGIN
    RETURN v_date;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then it compiles and runs without errors.

If you take this second version of Option 3 and declare `v_date` in a nested block then the answer is #4; however if you naively just use `RETURN v_date;` without delcaring `v_date` then the answer is #3.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b221c1abe717abcbf774eb140fd7d3c)*